# Wordpress Plugin development Call to undefined function jQuery()

Tags: plugins, jquery, customization

Seriously, I lost my whole day with this... Either I completely missed the point... Or I really cannot find the proper information on the internet...

Everywhere I find they say to load jQuery in the following way, in my main file of my plugin I do the following

This is the wp_enqueue_scripts (with an S) to load the scripts

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_load_jquery');
```

Then you need the function that calls for jQuery (wp_enqueue_script no S for this one).

```
function myplugin_load_jquery(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
};
```

What am I missing,

After doing that, I'm trying to use the following, and it always gives me the message "Call to undefined function jQuery()"

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //Do anything...
});
```

Can anyone finally tell me how to do that properly? In a clear manner? Or point me somewhere with proper and clear information?

Do I absolutely need to put my scripts inside a .JS file? Or I can run it from the same file?

... Working now... Doing more tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need specify jquery as a dependency of your custom script, setting the 3rd parameter of [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to `array('jquery')`, like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'yourCustomScript',
    plugins_url('js/yourCustomScript.js', __FILE__),
    array('jquery'),
    '1.0.0',
    false
);
```

*Change the path to point to your custom-script file*

As to your **last question**, the answer is affirmative. You need a .js file. Basically WP needs to know what scripts are loading in a page to make sure dependencies are loading first and none gets loaded twice.

Also keep in mind that your usual `$()` alias will not work unless you wrap your code in:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

[Refference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Here's a testing example that should work from inside a custom plugin:

#### jquery-test.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('<a/>', {
        id: 'foo',
        href: 'https://www.google.com/webhp?q=jquery+mistakes+you+are+probably+making',
        title: 'bar',
        rel: 'external',
        text: 'jQuery\'s dead! Long live jQuery!',
        style: '' +
            'position: fixed;' +
            'top: 120px; ' +
            'left: 0; ' +
            'padding: 10px 20px; ' +
            'background-color: #369; ' +
            'color: white; ' +
            'z-index: 9999;' +
            'border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0'
        })
    .prependTo('body');
});
```

Put this file in your plugin's `/js` folder.
In your plugin's main file, add this php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testing_jquery');
function testing_jquery() {
    if ( ! is_admin()) 
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'testing-jquery',
            plugins_url('js/testing-jquery.js', __FILE__ ),
            ['jquery'],
            true
            );
}
```

Make sure it's not inside any other function or class.

If you're not adding this via a plugin, but a theme, place the `testing-jquery.js` file in the theme's `/js` folder and replace `plugins_url('js/testing-jquery.js', __FILE__ ),` with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/testing-jquery.js',`

This should add a blue link to a google search for common mistakes when using jQuery to every frontend page of your website.

Comment: Hi Andrei, Thanks a lot for your time, could you give me a really simple example that I could run and see the results. I still try everything and cannot get it to work. Maybe it's where I make my enqueue call that am wrong, or the jQuery I do in the JS file that is wrong. if I could just have a quick example, or if you have any plugins that are REALLY simple to read and I could see the result I would be more than happy

Comment: Updated answer with a working example.

Comment: Doing some testing now... Thanks a lot for your time Andrei

Comment: Even though there is no Vote Up for your answers, you have the best answer to my question, and you are the one that spent the most time. I would add in your answer, that to load the jQuery this should be at the beginning of your main file to work properly, because too deep in your files and it might not load. I load both wp_enqueue and admin_enqueue at the beginning and everything seems to be working 100% - Thanks a WHOLE freaking lot for your help Andrei

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to specifically enqueue jQuery, as you're probably using jQuery in your custom script. You can do:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', plugin_url( 'js/my-script.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //Do anything...
});
```

Notice the $ passed as an arg to the callback, it will make jQuery accessible to your function scope.

Comment: The jQuery(document).ready(function($) part is going in the JS file? Or can still be inside the PHP? I'm sorry with everything I read I'm so confused now

Comment: Note that it should be `js/my-script.js` instead of `/js/my-script.js` because the value returned by [`plugins_dir_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) already has a trailing slash.

Comment: @pSyToR The document ready should go into the JS file, not the PHP.

Comment: Andrei's answer is better than mine :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure jQuery has been loaded, so output your code in a late action, eg for front end you could use `'wp_print_footer_scripts'` with a large priority:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //Do anything...
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}, 50 );
```

Similarly for admin `'admin_print_footer_scripts'`.

Comment: Why not not add jQuery as a dependency?

Comment: If you've got your code in a .js file then absolutement, that's the way to do it, but if you haven't....?!

Comment: @RRikesh what do you mean?

Comment: @Bonger no no it's not I was wondering if I had to

Comment: @bonger why wouldn't you have? It's better to put things in a JS file for caching.

Comment: @pSyToR are you adding any other JS files besides jQuery? You can add jQuery as a dependency, meaning WordPress will automatically include jQuery when it includes your JS file. Sometimes you can have such errors if you're including jQuery twice! Look at your source code.

Comment: My source code is clean I started from scratch my scripts are empty... because I was creating slowly from scratch build the admin page before starting to go deeper... I think next step will be to try and include a JS file instead

Comment: @RRikesh well I agree with you really (though I could list a few reasons) but was trying to address pSyTor's issue ... anyway I see things have moved on...

Comment: Yes, the question itself is confusing.

Answer (score -3):

Simply follow these steps, in my case my plugin name is awesome social icons.

```
   //  Step - 1
<?php
  function register_awesome_social_submenu_page()
    {
    add_submenu_page('options-general.php', 'Awesome Social', 'Awesome Social', 'manage_options', 'awesome-social', 'awesome_social_callback');
    }
  ?>
   // Step - 2
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_awesome_social_submenu_page');
?>
 // Step - 3

<?php 
function awesome_social_callback()
{
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-form');
?>
<script>
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

        $j(document).ready(function(){

// Do what you want :)
});
</script>

<?php

    }

?>
```

Comment: You still have to surround the jQuery script call between <script></script> I read everywhere it's not good practice?

Comment: There is noting wrong with practice.