# Add `datetimepicker` to form

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, datepicker

I have a form where i would like to add a `datetimepicker()`.
I must be doing something wrong.

I have done the following:
In my `header.php`

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

In my `functions.php`

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
```

In my `template.php`

```
<form id="" name="" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="MyDate" name="MyDate" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#MyDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function
```

I see the `<input>` element but if I click in it nothing happens.
This all comes from the following [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-jquery-datepicker)

Hope anyone sees my mistake(s)!
M.

Comment: This problem is already solved here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207203/uncaught-typeerror-datepicker-is-not-a-functionanonymous-function

Comment: did you added jquery-ui.js file? i think you are missing it. just add it after your jquery library , i hope that will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpcustom_enqueue_script' );
function wpcustom_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'datepicker-style', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js-datepicker', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js', array('jquery'), null, true); 
}
```

Readmore: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the scripts are loaded in the footer action while your script is loaded before.

So, what I would try:
Add your scripts via th proper action: [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

```
function wpse_206140_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_206140_enqueue_script' );
```

If you still run into the problem: Consider to external your script into a file and enqueue this file in dependency of `jquery-ui-datepicker`, see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

**Also: Check wp_head() and wp_footer()**
Another possible reason could be, your theme does not execute the [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) and [`wp_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) actions. Check your header.php and footer.php for `wp_header()` and `wp_footer()`. These functions need to be placed there.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: No Luck, I have tried: https://phptechnologytutorials.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/use-wordpress-default-jquery-ui-datepicker-in-your-theme/. This still doesn't work but also doesn't give me an error!

Comment: Maybe your theme does not execute the wp_footer() or wp_head() action.

Comment: It's a custom theme. The `header.php` executes `wp_head()`. Could it be that because the `wp_head()` allready does the enquement of the jquery it fails? I'll try! -> nope!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `wp_print_footer_scripts` action (front-end) or `admin_print_footer_scripts` action (back-end) with a large priority to ensure your javascript gets executed as late as possible, eg

```
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', function () {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#MyDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}, 50 );
```

(cf https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175855/57034)